# exporting a comma separated values text file to use in excel

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel, csv

In my C# winforms program I want to make an export function that will create a comma separated text file or csv. I am not sure about the logic of how to do this the best way. My exported file will be like this :

```
Family Name, First Name, Sex, Age
Dekker, Sean, Male, 23
Doe, John, Male, 40
```

So the first line I want to be the name of the columns, and the rest should be treated as values. Is it ok in this way for later usage? Or I should not include column names?

Would be nice to hear your experiences about this!

Comment: Its always good to receive data under suitable headings rather than figuring it out

Comment: I tried to put this file into excel but first row is also treaded as values. is there a way to comment this first line as header or something? or how can it go automaticly inside the column name instead of A, B, C, D in excel?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to achieve that, thats how excel works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sean,

sorry don't have enough privilege points to comment directly on your post. I think you may be confusing CSV and Excel files here. A CSV is simply a text file where each value is separated by a comma, there is no special formating etc. Excel will display CSV files since it knows how to open them but you can just as easily open them in notepad.

Excel .xslx files are different and can contain all sorts of different formats, charts etc. To format these files its important to understand that .xslx files are essentially zips. So the first place to start is to create an excel file with some data, save it and then rename the extension to .zip

Open the zip file created now and you will see a number of different folders and files, of these the most important for your purposes is the XL directory. In this folder  you will see a shared strings xml file and a worksheets folder.

Lets start by going into the worksheet folder and opening sheet1.xml. Look for the line that says "

If there is text in this column, i.e. data that excel should read as text then you will have something like 0. This indicates that cell A1 is of type string t="s" and that the value is to be found as the first value in the SharedStrings.xml file 0

If there is a number in the cell then you may have something like 234. In this case Excel knows to use the value 234 in this cell.

So in your case you will need to do the following:

1: create the excel document in C# - there are a number of libraries available for this

2: Open the excel file as a zip

3: Modify in your case the styles and worksheets xml files

4: Save the document

Answer (score 1):

That is absolutely fine to do (to state the obvious....). Excel has a little checkbox that allows the user importing to use the first line as column headers if they select it.

I would also suggest that you leave out the spaces at the start of each piece of data, it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In general its best practice to include the column headers, the only reason not to do so would be an external program over which you have no control accessing your data which doesn't realise that the first row are the column headers and which can't be changed.

To create the export function something like this should work:

```
private static List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // add some people
        people.Add(
            new Person() { firstName = "John", familyName = "Smith", sex = Sex.Male, age = 12 }
            );
        people.Add(
            new Person() { firstName = "Mary", familyName = "Doe", sex = Sex.Female, age = 25 }
            );

        // write the data
        Write();
    }

    static void Write()
    {
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\junk1\test.csv", false))
        {
            // write the header
            tw.WriteLine("Family Name, First Name, Sex, Age");

            // write the details
            foreach(Person person in people)
            {
                tw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", person.familyName, person.firstName, person.sex.ToString(), person.age.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
///  Applicable sexes
/// </summary>
public enum Sex
{
    Male,
    Female
}

/// <summary>
/// holds details about a person
/// </summary>
public class Person
{
    public string familyName { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public Sex sex { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dataset to do this.

Please refer [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Cs_CSV_import_export.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
  //Why not save the lines to a List<string> object, first List<sting>Object.Add//("your       headers"), use the string.Join("," "your Header Array string[]" do not add //(+",")   the .Join extension menthod will handle that for you.
```

//      here is an example 
      //if you were to retreive the header values from a database using a SQL Reader

```
  var reader = sqlcmdSomeQueryCommand.ExecuteReader();
  var columns = new List<string>();
  //get all the field names  from the Columns var 
  for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < reader.FieldCount; intCounter++)
  {
      columns.Add(reader.GetName(intCounter));
  }
  strarryTmpString = columns.ToArray();
  string TmpFields = string.Join(", ", strarryTmpString);
  columns.Clear();
  columns.Add(TmpFields); 

  //you can save the TmpFieldList to later add the rest of your comma delimited fields 



write line by line in a foreach loop or use the List<string> object .foreach(delegate(string delString)
{
  someStreamWriterObject.WriteLine(delString)
});
```